# Running a different thread does not allow the activity to be displayed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-activity, java.util.concurrent

I have this piece of an activity:

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResultListener {
    private String code = "";
    private String data = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

            code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
            data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

            MyExternal.DecodeAndSend(this, code, data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `MyExternal` is a class in other library.

The method `DecodeAndSend` is something like this:

```
public static boolean DecodeAndSend(ResultListener caller, String codigo, String data)
{
    try {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        HashMap<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();

        Future<String> resultado = pool.submit(new ServerConnection(caller, url, arguments));

        String status = resultado.get();
        if (status.equals("OK"))
            caller.OnSuccess();
        else
            caller.OnError(status);

        pool.shutdown();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, `ServerConnection` class implements `Callable<String>` so I show you the `call` method:

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    

    return "OK";
}
```

The call to `Thread.sleep(2000);` is actually a call to a web server to send some data.

The problem is that the `ResultActivity` does not show its layout until the `call` call returns.

What is missing in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecodeAndSend` is called from the main thread. It calls `Future.get()` which waits for the job to finish, so it's blocking the main thread. You should call this method from a background thread as well. I think it would be okay to send it to your same thread pool since it is submitted after the first job that it will wait for.

You cannot return anything about the request results from this method, because it is asynchronous.

```
public static void DecodeAndSend(ResultListener caller, String codigo, String data)
{
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    HashMap<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();

    Future<String> resultado = pool.submit(new ServerConnection(caller, url, arguments));

    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run () {
            try {
                String status = resultado.get();
                if (status.equals("OK"))
                    caller.OnSuccess();
                else
                    caller.OnError(status);

                pool.shutdown();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            caller.OnError(null); // No status, only an exception
    });
}
```

However, your `ServerConnection` class already takes a `caller` parameter, so it should probably just handle the callback itself. And depending on what you're doing in the callback, you might want to post the callback calls to the main thread.

By the way, convention in Java is to always start method names with a lower-case letter (camel case).

Comment: If I use the `caller` inside the `ServerConnection` to notify the status at the task, where can I call `pool.shutdown`? P.S. I came from C# world, and even when C# also uses camel case as the standard, the method names should start with upper-case. I will change all method names to follow Java convention.

Comment: You can call it right after the `pool.submit()` call. Already submitted jobs still run to completion after calling `shutDown()`. (I also use C#. One of the annoying things about using multiple languages is this difference in convention. I personally prefer the Java way because it makes functions stand out from constructors better, both at the declaration site and the call site.)

Answer (score 1):

`Feature.get()` is a blocking call. The UI Thread is blocked waiting for that call to return, hence can't take care of drawing your layout. Try passing the result listener to `ResultListener` to the `ServerConnection` and use the two callbacks to update your UI accordingly

Answer (score 0):

`Future.get()` is a [blocking call](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future) - execution stops until the result arrives

> The result can only be retrieved using method get when the computation has completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.

So your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method calls that stuff, and then blocks until `call` (which is running on another thread) returns its result. So `onCreate` doesn't finish, and the layout doesn't complete.

If you want to use that blocking code, but after the view has laid out, I'd use another part of the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) like `onStart` (set a flag so you only run it once!). Otherwise you'll need to use some other concurrency technique to get your result and use it. It depends on what you're actually doing with the result of your `call` function